# Is it possible to specify user specific pre commands in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

We have a slew of folks doing development through the same GitLab repo. We are using VS Code tasks to execute internal commands. The main command is the same for everyone: `internal_command` on Windows and `internalCommand` on Linux.

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label" : "do it",
            "type" : "shell",
            "windows": {
                "command": "internal_command"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "internalCommand"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This works as expected.

**Some** users need/want to run a specific command **before** the main command. For example, one use wants to rename a file, another user wants to change an environment variable, etc...

We don't want to have multiple versions of `.vscode/tasks.json` cause that is a mess when pushing things to GitLab.

**So I am wondering if there is a way to specify user specific tasks in the project's `.vscode/tasks.json` file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with the help of the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) it allows you to use the [content of a file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content) as a command in the terminal. The file can also contain [Key-Value pairs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content-key-value-pairs) or be a [JSON](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#file-content-json-property) file.

Say you store this `userTask.txt` or `userTask.json` file in the `.vscode` folder and add the file to the `.gitignore` file.

With the current version of the extension the file `userTask.txt` **has** to exist, I will add an option to supply alternative text in case the file does not exist. You can fill the file with a dummy command like `echo No User Task`

Set up your `task.json` like

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label" : "do it",
      "type" : "shell",
      "windows": {
        "command": "internal_command"
      },
      "linux": {
        "command": "internalCommand"
      },
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn": ["userTask"]
    },
    {
      "label" : "userTask",
      "type" : "shell",
      "command": "${input:getUserTask}"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "getUserTask",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.content",
      "args": {
        "fileName": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/userTask.txt"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```